# Facebook graph API to get get posts from Pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm struggling in getting the posts from the public page in Facebook. For example

> https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola
> (Its a public page, those who liked it on facebook will get update.)

This returns me the page details only. How I can get the wall posts done by the user "cocacola".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its quite simple. just do as

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/f‌​eed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed)

It will work.

Comment: Maybe something has changed in the API. It doesn't work now. Better use /feed

Comment: but using feed we cant get posts by the page.

Comment: Mine does not work through the request class. When I use the browser, it works fine for both endpoints but when I run my code, it returns nothing.

Comment: im having the same issue too. Anyone has a way around this?

Comment: feed and posts seem to do the same thing

Comment: Feed retrieves all the posts, status updates and links published by the page or other people in the page. /{page-id}/posts retrieve only the posts published by the page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Comment: Hello guys, is it still possible e.i. fetch posts from any public page.  
Or at least some hook when they publish any post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late at the party but for completeness I would like to add:

Using the latest version 2.2 you can access the feed via the page id, eg:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/PAGE_ID/feed?access_tkoen=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Individual posts can be retrieved too by their own id or via the feed.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/POST_ID?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Maybe this was also possible with the older versions? Don't know, I'm just getting started.