# how to retrieve facebook posts with facebook api and php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I found this post
[Facebook graph API to get get posts from Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275656/facebook-graph-api-to-get-get-posts-from-pages)

but when I followed its instructions, my return json was

```
{
"data": [

]
}
```

How can I retrieve the posts from a facebook page? I will need to do this in php to then modify and display the data.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I haven't written any code in php yet, I simply went to the url https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/posts?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with an accesstoken which I created on graph api developer.

Comment: If I am doing something wrong, please tell me.

Comment: change the word posts with feeds

Comment: now got this message: {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /feeds",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}

Comment: use this https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user& access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

Comment: so you need to have a valid OAUTH token , the error is pretty obvious

Comment: which access permissions do I need?

Comment: get a valid OAUTH TOKEN and hit the URL using that TOKEN

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36467/discussion-between-user1015214-and-satya)